# Password Protection iPhone app

Tags: ios, xcode, passwords

I have read the other posts about password protecting your application, but my situation is a little different.

I still want password protection, but I want to create the passwords myself, and then once a password is used, no other user can enter it.

Lets say I have a list of passwords (hamAndCheese, hamAndCheese1, hamAndCheese2).  If 1 person downloads the app from the app store and enters hamAndCheese, I want that password to be "broken" if another user tries to enter it.

Also, once a user enters the password once, I don't want them to have to enter it again. (Im less worried about this part, more about the part described above).

Should I just make a list of passwords? How do I eliminate them once they have been used?

Thank you

Comment: "and then once a password is used, no other user can enter it. " - that is poor design for passwords. Are you talking about serial/product keys?

Comment: You'll have to keep track of passwords on the server side, obviously

Comment: If I knew the perfect solution to this problem, I probably wouldn't have asked.  Im not sure how to handle it.

Comment: Yeah.  Product keys that come with software is pretty much what I want.

How would I handle it server side? Like contacting an external server?

Comment: Why do you have this problem, though? What exactly are you trying to accomplish? The fact that you say "password" implies that the user needs to associate themselves with an "account". However, the fact that you would _know_ what the password is implies that you would be storing it somewhere in plaintext? Not a good idea.

Comment: I have this problem because the app itself would be free, but a user would only be able to use it if they were involved in the program (the app is for a friend of mine who is a chemistry tutor.  He wants kids to be able to access all the info, but only if they are in his course.  He doesn't want to tutor 1 kid and have that kid share all of his info with his friends for free).

Comment: Apple's never going to allow this into the app store

Comment: Really? Good to know, thank you.  How do you suggest I handle this problem then?

Comment: Why not let the user enter a password locally on the iPhone, create a hash and send this to be stored on your server. 
You can also encrypt the hash in transit if you wanted to.
You could then refuse passwords that generated the same hash?

Comment: That is a very good idea.  I also thought that the tutor could keep a QR code with him, and that way the student would scan the QR code (it wouldn't save a picture to their phone), and that would unlock the app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You could make a time-dependent password.
   you generate a list of passwords, and the viability of the pw is only a few days. This makes reduces the risk that your passwords will travel after the time they are useful
2. Second option is a webservice that you built, and that validates the password over the internet
3. As stated before by tux91 - sounds like it could be used to generate a revenue stream outside the appstore, leaving big bad apple without it's 30% cut of your revenues